# Table divider/bold row line in GitLab Flavored Markdown

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I have made a long table in GitLab, but would like to divide the rows within the table to highlight different groups. I would wish for a bold table row line as a divider or different background colors for the different groups.

From what I have read, it does not seem to be possible by using only the GitLab Flavored Markdown syntax, and the closest I have come is to use an empty row as a divider, but I am not fully satisfied with that solution.

```
| ---- |Precision | Recall | F1 | Support |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |---- | ---- |
| Group 1 |0.5 | 0.6 | 0.55 | 5 |
| Group 1 |0.5 | 0.6 | 0.55 | 5 |
|      |    |     |      |   |
| Group 2 |0.5 | 0.6 | 0.55 | 5 |
| Group 2 |0.5 | 0.6 | 0.55 | 5 |
```

results in this:

[image]

Are there any other ways to do this more nicely? Perhaps with html/css?

Comment: What do you mean by a "bold table row line"? In both markdown and HTML tables, you could add some text and bold it. While it's not possible in markdown, you could add a background colour to a specific row in an HTML version of the table

Comment: @Arty-chan I think he means a thick line

Comment: Ah figures. It's not possible to change the border styling in markdown. I don't think any flavour of MD support that.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. Then I will have to accept my current solution. @Arty-chan

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at the [gitlab markdown guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/). A bold line separator isn't possible but the guide describes some options you can try to make your Groups differ:

### [mix html and markdown](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/#mix-html--markdown-markup)

you can add html elements in your markdown. You could use that to color your groups differently

### [styles](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/#styles)

gitlab markdown allows you to define styles in your document:

```
<style>
  .purple {
    color:inherit;
  }
  .purple:hover {
    color:rgb(107,79,187);
  }
</style>
```

You can then apply this style like this:

```
Hey! Hover the cursor over me and guess what?! :)
{: .purple}
```

Maybe those options help you